# Стоит ли заострять внимание на нерешённых задачах?

Tags: c

Учу программирование, сейчас прохожу C с рекурсиями, не могу решить пару задач, потратил кучу времени, и задался вопросом, как правильнее: решить до конца "кровь из носу" или оставить на потом? Что можно в таком случае посоветовать? Просто остаётся такое ощущение, что потом пригодится, а не решил. Кто что подскажет?

Comment: @DreamChild: почему не как ответ?

Comment: @VladD - потому что скромность красит человека

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Оставьте на потом. Уж лучше решить десяток задач попроще, чем не решить пару посложнее. Может так получиться, что решение лежит где-то рядом, и чем больше вы пытаетесь решить, тем больше зацикливаетесь на неправильных вариантах. В таких случаях полезнее отвлечься и вернуться к вопросу позже со свежей головой. Возможно, сможете решить их, когда наберетесь опыта. Так или иначе, вряд ли имеет смысл биться над одними и теми же задачами, если они вам не нужны кровь из носу

Answer (score 4):

Решать обязательно, именно такие задачи, которые не решаются с первого раза, они и развивают мозги. Сиди, упирайся, но реши обязательно. А если считаешь, что понадобится, то тем паче.

Comment: Упираться надо, но не слишком сильно.  Потому что бывают алгоритмически неразрешимые задачи :-)

Comment: @Egor_Skriptunoff   

> сейчас прохожу "C"  

Скорее всего товарищ читает учебник или слушает лекции. Не думаю, что автор засунул в учебник алгоритмически неразрешимые задачи. Ну если только just for lulz...  

----  

> но не слишком сильно  

А как по-другому? Ну вот надо будет ему по работе запилить алгоритм. У него не получилось сразу. Что делать - костыль или забить на это? Нет уж, задачу придется решить. Хороший программист не тот который знает всё, а тот который может найти решение поставленной задачи.

Comment: плюсую этот ответ, ибо "потом" может и не наступить вовсе...